# $\text {Let }H(x)=(\int^{\pi}_{\sin(x)}\frac{t}{\cos(t)}dt)^3$ Find $H'(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

$$\text {Let }H(x)=(\int^{\pi}_{\sin(x)}\frac{t}{\cos(t)}dt)^3$$

My steps:

$$H(x) = (-\int^{\sin(x)}_{\pi} \frac{t}{\cos(t)}dt)^3$$
$$H'(x) = 3(-\int^{\sin(x)}_{\pi} \frac{t}{\cos(t)}dt)^2\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(\sin(x)}\cos(x)$$
$$H'(x) = \frac{3\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\cos(\sin(x))}(-\int^{\sin(x)}_{\pi} \frac{t}{\cos(t)}dt)^2$$

Is this correct.

Also can I pull the negative sign out or not? It's squared, so can I really?

Comment: Your solution is fine.  The minus sign is squared, and so $(-1)^2=1$.

Comment: I think there is a missing minus sign in the second line where you take the derivative of the negative integral, so you should end up with a negative sign out front.